# Unit testing, database approach with JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mongoose

I m developping Nodejs (ES6) applications using Mongoose, and I was wondering what could be the aim of unit testing this function :

```
getAll(){
  return MongooseUserShema.find({}).exec();
}
```

Actually, Mongoose is a well known library, many people use it, and it's well tested.

Wouldn't it be redunbdant if I try to unit test this "facade" ?

I know the importance of testing, but if I don't have any logic inside of my functions, except calls from external libraries (well tested), I was wondering what could be the aim in this case ?

Answer (score 2):

Using Mockito api, create mocks.Use

```
Mockito.when(<service_call>).thenReturn(<answer>);
```

and then verify how many times they were called using

```
Mockito.verify();
```

Unit testing is important so as to ensure that all external service calls are occuring expected number of times and the functionality with which the method was written is acchieved.

Answer (score 1):

You should not test how Mongoose `find()` method works. You should write test that confirms its call. I would advice you to stub Mongoose with something like [`mongoose-mock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-mock) + [`proxyquire`](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire), and then make an assertion which will verify if `find()` method was called.